# Brave Browser / Bug with scrolling - Return to top of the page

Tags: html, browser, scroll, brave

There is a bug regarding scrolling when opening https://www.streampicker.de/ with the Brave Browser. After scrolling down a bit, the website jumps back to the top.

Video to show it in action: https://www.dropbox.com/s/37suikq9awxix7c/StreamPicker%20-%20Brave%20Browser%20-%20Scrolling.mov?dl=0

It works perfectly with all other browsers including Chrome. Brave is on the latest version with no other external extensions installed.

Any ideas what could cause that problem and how to fix it - in the browser or in the code of the website itself?

Comment: I assume that it is because the site has refreshed one or more elements.  I get this on other sites with  Firefox, Brave and Chrome.  I am blaming this on Windows, because on restarting Windows they work. I think its mis-processing the scroll wheel on the mouse.

Comment: @RohitGupta Thanks for your help! Do you have any idea to figure out which elements could cause this problem? We are happy to change / improve code to ensure that users can access the site with Brave as well.

Comment: Sorry, no I have no idea.  Maybe its the brand of mice.  I use Logitech M705

Comment: You could try disabling scripts on the page (via the Brave Shields, located to the right of the address bar). If that causes the jumping to stop, then a script on the page was responsible (and not the browser itself).

Answer (score 0):

If are using web extensions please remove one by one and check that scroll bar issue fixed or not. That may be occurs for new brave updates with older versions of our extensions may not be support.

**Try also these steps**

**Solutions:**

Step 1: Go to `brave://flags` and enable 'Overlay Scrollbars'. Do `Ctrl+F` and search for overlay, and you'll just dropdown the menu to enable it. This was actually the part provided by Brave support, so thanks guys!

Step 2: Check your extensions and disable your adblockers. One in particular that was blocking it for me was uBlock, as soon as I disabled uBlock on those websites they immediately worked after a reload.

I used uBlock on Chrome also and BOTH browsers had the default settings but Brave didn't show the scroll bars on those particular websites? No idea, it got me for a while though.

There was mention of Logitech software for Keyboards/Mice interfering also.